# html5 video autoplay delay in safari

Tags: javascript, css, html, video

I am embedding a html5 video. It works perfectly fine in chrome and firefox, however in safari, there seems to be this weird delay, where the video just hangs in there, and won't play until 1-2 minutes after. It however plays immediately, if I switch tabs. I am hosting my video on an Amazon S3, I set it to autoplay, muted and loop. I have tried using jquery to force play the video but it doesn't work. I have tried also changing the metadata to video/mp4 on aws control panel, also doesn't work. Also tried doing some window focusing, also doesn't work. Any tips would be appreciated. Here is the site http://xxvii27.github.io/web-oconnect/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved, by converting the .mp4 video to web optimized version using handbrake.

Comment: +1 to this, turns out safari somehow processes the video differently from other browsers. My guess - it does not play it by chunks, it waits for the whole 30MB video to get downloaded, and only then starts it. Now, I don't know if we can force Safari to play it by chunks, but optimizing video with handbrake, made it go down to 16MB, which is played almost instantly. Good enough for me.